# EXPO - Как подключить готовую БД?

Tags: javascript, sqlite3, react-native, expo

Есть приложение на React Native с Expo CLI.

Задача - интегрировать в него внешнюю готовую бд SQLite в 0,5 гб.

Проблема в том, что Expo не работает с плагином sqlite3, а родной плагин - exposqlite не содержит документации о подключении внешней БД.

Как интегрировать базу?